# Nginx - rewrite fastcgi_param for one specific route

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

I want to change `fastcgi_param` only for specific routes as described below:

```
server {
    # (...)

    # PHP entry point for main application
    location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Changed memory_limit for that path
    location ^~ ^/rewritten_path {
        # Change memory_limit only for all routes: example.com/rewritten_path/...
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=1024M \n max_execution_time=18000";
        # Allow /index.php$is_args$args
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a new value using `fastcgi_param` within another `location` block, but you will need to include the complete context, all the other `fastcgi_param` statements and the `fastcgi_pass` statement.

It would be simpler to use a variable within the existing `location` block. You could define the variable using a `map`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $php_value {
  default             "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
  ~^/rewritten_path   "memory_limit=1024M \n max_execution_time=18000";
}
server {
    ...
    location ... {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        ...
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE  $php_value;
        ...
    }
}
```